# Numerical problem with set of ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab

I have a set of ODEs:

$$\dot{x}_{i} = f_i(x_1, \ldots, x_N), ~ i \in \{1, 2, \ldots, N\}$$

This set of ODE has the following properties:

1. $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^N f_i = 0 ~ \forall x_1, \ldots, x_N$
2. If $\displaystyle x_i(0) \geq 0 ~ \forall i$ and $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^N x_i(0) = 1$ then $\displaystyle x_i(t) \geq 0 ~ \forall i, t > 0$ and $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^N x_i(t) = 1 ~\forall t > 0$
3. When $x_i(t) = 0$ or $x_i(t) = 1$ then $\dot{x}_i(t) = 0 ~ \forall x_j(t), i\neq j$.

Having said that, I have numerical problem while simulating these set of ODEs.
In particular, I sometime get that for some $t>0$, I found $x_i(t) > 1$ or $x_i(t) < 0$. These errors can be small ($x_i(t) = 1 + 10^{-7}$ or $x_i(t) = 0 - 10^{-7}$) or even ''great'' ($x_i(t) = 1 + 10^{-3}$ or $x_i(t) = 0 - 10^{-3}$).

For simulation, I use standard MATLAB functions ode45, ode23 & co.

How can I prevent this behavior?
If needed, I can add other details!

Comment: Hard to say much without seeing your code and the exact equations in question. Remember that numerical integration is not exact. You should look at and understand the tolerance options for the various solvers. The `'NonNegative'` option might even be helpful. If this question is really about how to use Matlab to solve your system, rather than about the mathematics of numerical integration, then you might ask your question (with code) at [StackOverflow/Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab).

Comment: You can find equations here: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1307.1670v1.pdf. See equation (5), (6) and (9).

Comment: I'm using Matlab for ode solving in a very standard way. I don't know if there is some particular trick to avoid such situation.

Comment: The `'NonNegative'` option should keep every thing greater than or equal to zero. Adjusting tolerances should help. You're seeing some kind of numerical overshoot. Without seeing the behavior of the system I don't know if it's stiff. Have you tried `ode15s`?

Comment: Another option is to write your own integrator and incorporate a thresholding function. For Euler and a scalar system this would look something like: `y(i+1) = min(max(y(i)+f(t,y(i))*dt,0),1);`, where `y` is your state variable, `dt` is your step size, and `f` is your ODE function. The `max` and `min` functions are a fast way to bound the output between 0 and 1. A sigmoid function would work too. And you could implement this using RK4 or a more advanced scheme. The key is that the threshold is applied on each step after integration – this can't be done via the ODE functions used by `ode45`.